# Get the full number using intlTelInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am using the demo code for intlTelInput provided [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html)

I am able to get the dial code using following

```html
var intlNumber = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData");
```

But i am not able to get the full number i.e. "dialcode + number entered by user" from the #phone text box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `getnumber` option, so in your case:

`var intlNumber = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber");`

^ This will give you the entire number (country code + phone number)

See [docs](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#troubleshooting) here.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the built-in methods for getting the full number but you must add the utilsScript

```
 $("#phone").intlTelInput(
    { 
      //Other configurations,
      //Other configurations,
      utilsScript : "/path/to/build/utils.js",

    });
```

in the initialization for the intlTelInput as stated here [Intl-Tel-Phone Docs](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/tree/v13.0.4)

and then you can get the full number by using

```
$("#YourInputElementID").intlTelInput("getNumber");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `full_phone` is gonna do the trick.
It will append a hidden field with full number when submitting the form.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
window.intlTelInput(input, {
    hiddenInput: "full_phone",
    utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js" 
});
```

**updated:**
if the above trick didn't work then don't worry you can fix it by putting a hidden input field before the phone input field.

**HTML:**

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone"),
  hidden= document.querySelector("#hidden");

var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  nationalMode: true,
  utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js" 
});

var handleChange = function() {
hidden.value = iti.getNumber()
};
```

// listen to "keyup", but also "change" to update when the user selects a country

```
input.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
input.addEventListener('keyup', handleChange)
```

Comment: what are you doing? There is already a hidden input with the formatted and cleaned number, just use the method provided by the plugin

Answer (score 0):

**Submitting form with ajax .**
This worked for me.
I added the `hiddenInput : "full_phone"` and change the even listener from `"submit"` to `"change"` in the `intlTelInput.js` file

```
 var iti = document.querySelector("#phone");
  window.intlTelInput(iti, {
    separateDialCode: true,
    hiddenInput : "full_phone",
    utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js",
  });
```

In the `intlTelInput.js` file

```
 if (this.telInput.form) this.telInput.form.addEventListener("change", this._handleHiddenInputSubmit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply use getInstance and then getNumber

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone"),
window.intlTelInput(input, {
      utilsScript : "/path/to/build/utils.js",
  });
window.intlTelInputGlobals.getInstance(input).getNumber();
```